# Does MSP430 and AVR have internal pull-up on UART's RXD line?

Tags: avr, msp430

Suppose a device with MSP430 or AVR microcontroller and floating UART lines (e.g. to external connector). Need I add an external pull-up to the RXD line?

Comment: Isn't this information in the respective data sheets? Have you looked?

Comment: @JoeHass: Yes, I've looked it. I didn't find any information for my question, but there are no pull-up resistors showed in block diagrams.

Comment: Please add a link to the datasheets of both chips.

Comment: Perhaps you need to clarify your question. Are you asking whether specific devices have internal pullups or are you asking in general whether a UART RX input needs a pullup? If it's the former, you need to dig deeper in the literature.

Comment: @JoeHass: Almost sure it don't differ inside a family. But maybe it differ between AVR and MSP430 families.

Comment: @jippie: my previous comment for you too.

Comment: I know it doesn't differ for AVR (at least the ones I am familiar with), but I am too lazy to first find a datasheet and then find the related chapter too.

Answer (score 3):

1. Find the datasheet of the device
2. Figure out which pins have the UART functionality
3. Figure out if the output drivers for these pins support pull up / down resistors
4. Check the text of the I/O pin drivers in the datasheet if any exceptions are made for UART mode

For AVR all pins support pull up (except Vcc, GND and except RESET to some extent) you can turn on pull up resistors by setting Data Direction Register for a pin as input and enable the pull up by setting the corresponding pin in the PORT register.

Comment: In MSP430 user can switch pin between perephiral modules. If I set up internal pull-up resistor in GPIO, does it stay when I switch pin to UART?

Comment: Not really familiar with MSP430 series.

Comment: You should be looking at the **INPUT** docs, not the output driver ones.

Comment: Updated the text.